# How do I deal with 'package ‘mudata’ is not available for this version of R'

Tags: r, r-package

I tried to install the mudata package in the RStudio Cloud using:

```
install.packages("mudata")
library(mudata)
```

I get the following output:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘mudata’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

I followed the link but found nothing about the mudata package.
Does anyone have any ideas how to go about that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
The package 'mudata' is now 'mudata2'.