# Unable to install the R dataPreparation package in the cloudera data science workbench

Tags: r, cloudera, r-package, cran, install.packages

I am trying to install dataPreparation package in the cloudera data science workbench. It has R 4.0.5 version presently installed.

The following command

```
install.packages("dataPreparation", dependencies = TRUE)
```

throws the following error:

[image]

I followed the link: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages, but could resolve nothing out of it.

Has the name of the package been changed as pointed by another thread related to another package?: [How do I deal with 'package ‘mudata’ is not available for this version of R'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71059069/how-do-i-deal-with-package-mudata-is-not-available-for-this-version-of-r)

I also tried the following to install from the source:

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/dataPreparation/dataPreparation_1.0.5.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

and got the following message:

[image]

What is going wrong and how to install it? The link for installing packages as proposed by cloudera doesn't help either here: https://docs.cloudera.com/cdsw/1.9.0/install-package-libraries/topics/cdsw-install-pkg-lib.html

I mean, trying the following:

```
install.packages('devtools') 
library(devtools)
install_github("ELToulemonde/dataPreparation")
```

produced the following after devtools was successfully installed:

[image]

Trying to install all the dependencies and then data Preparation finally did not work either.

Comment: Hello, if you get timeout error, I don't think it is linked to this package but to your network. Try another package you might get the same error. Are you behind a vpn ? is there a filtering on website you can access ?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the dataPreparation tar file from here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dataPreparation/index.html

Uploaded it in the project folder and ran the following commands, which made it finally work:

```
install.packages("dataPreparation_1.0.5.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
library('dataPreparation')
```